# Get the element with array and object

Tags: php, arrays, object

I spent over 2 hours looking for the solution, and I leave it to you because I am completely blocked. I try to learn the object in PHP. I created a function that return me the result of an SQL query.

Here is the var_dump return :

```
object(stdClass)[6]
  public 'name' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[11]
          public 'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => 
        object(stdClass)[12]
          public 'id' => string '5' (length=1)
```

I used a foreach to parse this, but I don't get directly **the id of each element**. And I especially don't want  to use another foreach.

```
foreach($function as $key => $value){
    var_dump($value->id);
}
```

But it doesn't work there.

Here is the function called who returns this result

```
public function nameFunction () {

    $obj = new stdClass();
    $return = array();

    $request = $this->getConnexion()->prepare('SELECT id FROM table') or die(mysqli_error($this->getConnexion()));

    $request->execute();
    $request->store_result();
    $request->bind_result($id);

    while ($request->fetch()) {
        $return[] = parent::parentFunction($id);
    }

    $obj->name = $return;

    $request-> close();

    return $obj;
}
```

And parent::parentFunction($id) returns :

```
object(stdClass)[11]
  public 'id' => string '1' (length=1)
```

Comment: Can you post the full code

Comment: Yes because we need to see if you are looping the array or the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping the object instead of array. Try to use this code

```
foreach($function->name as $key => $value){
    var_dump($value->id);
}
```

Tell me if it works for you

Comment: Yeah !!!! That's it ! Woow. I knew I was not far, but I needed a little push. Beautiful, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This  question might help you : 
[php parsing multidimensional stdclass object with arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600531/php-parsing-multidimensional-stdclass-object-with-arrays)

Especially answer from **stasgrin**

```
function loop($input)
{
    foreach ($input as $value)
    {
        if (is_array($value) || is_object($value))
            loop($value);
        else
        {
            //store data
            echo $value;
        }
    }
}
```